# How do I achieve this functionality in python?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pytest

I am writing automated UI tests in python and run by py.test. I am trying to make it as simple as possible for anybody who is writing tests. What I am trying to achieve is something like this.

```
def test_set_feature_example(self, fix_web_ui)
     A = fix_web_ui["features"]
     A.features.example = 'somestring' # What this should achieve is using selenium, set the text with the id 'features.example' with 'somestring'.
```

What this should achieve is using selenium, set the text with the id 'features.example' with 'somestring'. The ids in the UI are same as the one mentioned. This is possible if I can override the operator '='. Since that is not possible, is there any other way that I can achieve this sort of functionality. The other way that I thought is adding these functionality in the finalizer of fix_web_ui but that wouldn't work because that would mean restricting the fix_web_ui to a function. Any ideas please? Hope I am clear.

Before marking it as duplicate, I am not asking if the assignment can be overloaded. I am asking an architecture in which the person writing the tests can write something similar to this

```
A.features.example = 'somestring'
```

instead of

```
driver = webdriver.FireFox()
item  = driver.find_elements_by_id('features.example')
item.send_keys('somestring')
driver.close()
```

Comment: Look at `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`

Comment: The Page Object model might be what you are looking for: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html

Comment: @user1429322 could you try my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37479434/4988742 and comment if that solved your question. Otherwise if you solved please kindly share your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use fixture overriding functionality here http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#overriding-fixtures-on-various-levels

so if your fix_web_ui was a higher level fixture (scope="session") then you can override it on a module level. Your fix_web_ui fixture must be a mutable object.

```
# conftest.py

@pytest.fixture
def fix_web_ui():
    class Feature1(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.example = "example1"
    return {"features": Feature1()}
```

---

```
# test_feature.py

import copy

@pytest.fixture
def fix_web_ui(fix_web_ui):
     # here it depends how you want to handle this:
     # 1) modify original fixture values - that will persist for the outer scope too
     # 2) or make a copy of a the outer scope fixture and override it's attributes like this:
     fix_web_ui2 = copy.deepcopy(fix_web_ui)
     fix_web_ui2.example = "overridden"
     return fix_web_ui2

def test_feature_functionality(fix_web_ui):
    assert fix_web_ui.example == "overridden"
```